# How to permanently set Azure idle timeout for AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, nginx-ingress, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster with a Nginx ingress controller. This ingress controller creates a Loadbalancer, and I would like to increase the idle timeout.

I can set it easily enough, but after a few minutes the value is returned to 4 minutes. Is there an annotation or some other setting that allows me to save the new timeout value permanently?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up finding the annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-tcp-idle-timeout` from the source code at https://gowalker.org/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/azure. This isn't documented anywhere on the Azure site, but there are a bunch of annotations that might be useful in certain situations.